# How to load modifications made in native java classes?

Tags: java, command-line, prepared-statement

**Hi,**

I'm trying to execute a jar file, overwriting some java originals interfaces to connect with the database, changing the method `setBoolean` to receive an object like parameter.

**That's the original interface method:**

```
void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x) throws SQLException;
```

**That's my change:**

```
void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, Boolean x) throws SQLException;
```

My changes were made at interface java.sql.PreparedStatement. For my changes to be called, when I start the application I'm using the command:

```
java -verbose:class -Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Users/user/Desktop/myproject/src/main/java -jar safepdv.jar
```

With the command "-verbose:class" I can verify that the class with my changes are being loaded.

However, when the method `setBoolean` is called by the application, he isn't founded, and my return is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.sql.PreparedStatement.setBoolean(IZ)V
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.controller.ConfigurationController.updateCS(ConfigurationController.java:613)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.OpenMoviment.validaCamposLogin(OpenMoviment.java:448)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.OpenMoviment.passwordTextSenhaUsuarioActionPerformed(OpenMoviment.java:403)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.OpenMoviment.access$200(OpenMoviment.java:22)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.OpenMoviment$4.actionPerformed(OpenMoviment.java:240)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa.verificarMovimentoExistente(Caixa.java:3392)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa.<init>(Caixa.java:344)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa$41.run(Caixa.java:2393)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I make my method was really called instead of the original method?

Comment: What are you going to achieve using `Boolean`?

Comment: While your question is okay in my eyes, is this really necessary? 
Do you know about auto-unboxing, which basically solves this problem for you?
(It makes it so if you call the original function but with a Boolean argument, it basically calls 'Boolean#booleanValue()' on the argument before passing it to the method).

Comment: I see that you are using wrapper class - Boolean in your overriding method second argument, any reason for doing so ?

Comment: And how do you call the method `setBoolean()`

Comment: I'm trying to use `Boolean` because I cannot change the code of my project. As at one point in my project the `setBoolean` method with the parameters `(int parameterIndex, boolean x)` is getting `x` with the value `null`. I thought about changing the connector code ant treating this question, so I changed the `setBoolean` of `PreparedStament`.

Answer (score 0):

The calling code is still trying to pass a `null` value to the old method's signature (which expects a `boolean`, and not a `Boolean`). You would need to recompile the calling code so that it binds to the new method signature: the method signatures to be called are fixed at compile-time.

Also, note that `PreparedStatement` is an interface - changing its definition is likely to break all classes implementing said interface. Most notably, each JDBC driver will include its own implementation; you would have to recompile the drivers from source to fix this.

It is possible, but ugly and unmaintainable, to decompile the calling code and simply fix it at the point where the `null` is being passed, and then recompile it. You can automate this to a certain point (think bytecode-editing libraries), but the gist is that not having access to the source code making the bad calls is a severe drawback.